# Grammar help - zusehen/anrufen, why is it Dative and not

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, grammar-identification, standard-german

Translating this sentence "The parents are watching their children"

> Die Eltern sehen ihren Kindern zu.

<del>ihren Kindern is dative because of "zu" right? zusehen since the preposition "zu" is Dative</del> 
Okay so they are prefixes not prepositions

In this sentence however:

> The parents are calling their children.

I expect:

> Die Eltern rufen ihren Kindern an

<del>Thinking that "an" is a preposition that can be both Dative/Accusative depending on if there is "movement", and since there is no movement, it should be dative.</del>

However I get the following answer from DeepL and chatgpt (please dont question me using it, just if it's right or wrong):

> Die Eltern rufen ihre Kinder an

This is the answer Chatgpt gives (If you know the answer you can skip this):

> In the sentence "Die Eltern rufen ihre Kinder an.", "Die Eltern" is
> the subject of the sentence and is therefore in the nominative case.
> "Ihre Kinder" is the direct object of the verb "anrufen", which means
> that it receives the action of the verb. Direct objects in German are
> in the accusative case, so "ihre Kinder" must be in the accusative
> case.
>
> In the sentence "Die Eltern sehen ihren Kindern zu.", "Die Eltern" is
> still the subject of the sentence and is in the nominative case.
> However, the verb "zusehen" requires an indirect object, which means
> that "ihren Kindern" is in the dative case. In this sentence, "ihren
> Kindern" is the indirect object because it is the recipient of the
> action of "sehen", which is being done to the children indirectly
> through the act of observing them.

So how should I think in the matter? You can maybe delete this post after since it can probably be explained with a grammar sheet or whatever, but I just don't know and I've really tried.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the terms *direct object* and *indirect object* when it comes to German. Yes, they exist and the terms are applicable but that doesn't help you as a learner.

That is because you can't determine the direct object in a German clause easily. In English and Romance languages, there's a rule that the first object of a verb is its direct object.

**This rule does not apply to German.**

In German, the first object of a verb may be its indirect object. And verbs can take **any case** for their first object. And any case for their second object. Yes, the most common combination is a mandatory accusative object, which is the direct object, and an optional dative object, which is the indirect object. Same as in English, French etc.

BUT, there's

- a hundred verbs with no accusative object but a mandatory dative object
- a dozen verbs with a mandatory accusative and an optional genitive object
- a dozen verbs with a mandatory genitive object
- a dozen verbs with a mandatory accusative and a mandatory second accusative object
- a dozen verbs with a mandatory nominative predicative

Many of those irregular verbs are common.

So you have to learn it by verb which objects it wants. And you also have to learn by verb whether it wants a location or a direction or either, as you are at it.

---

> Die Eltern sehen ihren Kindern zu.

That item *ihren Kindern* is the dative object of the verb *zusehen*.

> Die Eltern rufen ihre Kinder an.

That item *ihre Kinder* is the accusative object of the verb *anrufen*.

The terms *indirect object* and *direct object* could be applied but they don't help you at all. It's the first object in both examples.

Comment: To be more specific, "ihre(n) Kinder" is a direct object by any reasonable definition of the term, but a direct object can have different cases in German depending on the verb. So "direct object" exists as a concept, but it's not a very useful concept for German. When there are two objects then it's almost always the case that the direct object is accusative and the indirect object is dative, but there are exceptions even to this seemingly basic rule.

Comment: No, *ihren Kindern* isn't a direct object. The test for that is what happens in the equivalent passive clause. By definition, direct objects become subjects in the passive clause. That's not what happens here. The passive clause is *Ihren Kindern wird zugesehen.* That's still dative. Not nominative. — Compare *Der Vater ruft den Sohn an.* It becomes *Der Sohn wird angerufen.* That's a direct object. It becomes the subject of the equivalent passive clause.

Comment: The direct object is the person or thing that is acted upon by the subject. In English the direct object changes to the the subject in a passive sentence, but it German it's the accusative object. Of course you could just define the direct object to the the accusative object in German, but that doesn't help. Btw, I don't think that direct object is the first object in English. It's either (subject) (verb) (indirect object) (direct object) e.g. "I gave the dog a bone" or (subject) (verb) (direct object) to (indirect object) e.g. "I gave a bone to the dog."

Comment: *First object* is not about word order but about what happens when a particular verb in a clause has no, one, two objects. In English and Romance languages, if it has one object, that's by rule the direct object. This rule does not exist in German. The first object a verb takes may be the indirect (dative) object.

Comment: — As I wrote, it makes little sense to talk about direct and indirect objects in German but if you do, you have to declare that object that becomes the subject in the passive clause the direct object because that's what the passive does to a clause: it makes the thing acted upon the subject.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work for German as there are those pesky verbs that don't have a direct object. But an indirect object. So forget about those terms and only think in terms of accusative, dative, genitive and nominative when it comes to German.

Comment: I don't know much about your way of learning grammar, but here in Sweden we just learn of direct and indirect objects, because they are pretty similar in both languages. For example, if I said: Ich habe einen Computer, because Computer is the direct object, hence accusative. This is the same as in Swedish and it always works except for prepositions and maybe if you have a really hard word order (but can still be done the same way I think). We take it out by determining what the subject, the verb and usually put: What/Whom + P + S? to get the direct object.

Comment: I already knew that some verbs change the case, we are also taught that, and I did search on it before I asked the question here, but it didn't see it as a dative verb even though it was. In Sweden we are taught to know the rule and the verbs and then it works. Isn't that how everyone is taught German?

Comment: German kids get taught about direct and indirect objects when they learn English. Those terms are not used when teaching German to German kids as they aren't useful.

Comment: Then how would you know if it's accusative masculine -en in a sentence where you don't have a preposition or verb that determines it? I guess for children they just learn it uknowningly, but for an adult learning it seems way more intuativ, since except for verbs and prepositions it always seems to hold true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144542/discussion-between-janka-and-nisse26a).

Answer (score 0):

The "zu" in the first sentence is not a word in itself, it's the prefix in the verb "zusehen" which has been separated and moved to the end of the sentence. It's not even a preposition really; you might call it a particle but I think it's more accurate to call it a separated verb prefix. Anyway, "zusehen" is a separable verb which happens to take a dative object, and that's why you get "ihren Kindern" in the dative. I don't know who or what Chatgpt is, but the information looks wrong to me.

Comment: But isn't anrufen also a seperable verb? an-rufen. "Zu" as a preposition is at least always Dative, but "an" can be either accusative or dative. However if that is the case when they are apart of a seperable verb I don't know. Hence the question

Comment: No, the *zu* in *zusehen* is not a preposition but a separable verb prefix. These are two different things.

Comment: @RHa Isn't the same true for an- in anrufen?

Comment: @nisse26a Right, the *an* in *anrufen* is also not a preposition.

Comment: @RHa yes, I understand that either they are all prepositions or they are not and I checked a lot of sources and it seems like prefixes, even if they are prepositions, if they are in a seperable verb they dont work as prepositions anymore. So why then does zusehen become dative and anrufen not?

Comment: There is no logic behind that. You have to remember it for each verb. … Yes, I hear you curse us all.

Comment: @Janka - Dative verbs are relatively rare, so it's easier to just memorize them.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT is right "anrufen" goes with a accusative while "zusehen" goes with a dativ.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why everyone here makes it so complicated...

Thanks Helena for the answer. Would've given the solution to you if I could.

Simple answer to my question, they both are direct objects, but "zu" even when used as a prefix in a seperable verb tends to takes the dative case (zuhören, zulächeln, zustimmen...). So it was simply that the verb takes Dative and the 2 websites I checked didn't have a full list of Dative verbs